# How to use idea to specify the javac run with java5 supported？

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

I am new to Java development, there is a project written in Java5, contains a lot of spring files and a folder named WebRoot, after using Intellij Idea import the project, it seems Idea recognized it's an “application”, if I "Rebuild” the project, it gives out a lot of warning, showing the java files could not be compiled

```
"Error:(17, 2) java: -source 1.3 doesn't support annotation
  (please use -source 5 or higher version to enable generics)"
```

I tried to add "-source 5" into the setting of javac， but it this leads to build failed. so where could I set this value？

Comment: What does it say in Project Settings -> Project -> Language Level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IntelliJ, you should first go to the ["Project Structure Dialog"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project-structure-dialog.html) and then to the ["General Settings Page"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project-general-settings-page.html). There you can set the "Project Language Level" to Java 5.0.